# Export URL for code organisation

Tags: react-native

I'm fairly new to React native, and i would like to have all my endpoints URLs in the same place

So, i have in my environement.js:

```
module.exports = {
 SERVER: 'http://url.com',
 API_VERSION: '/api/v3',
 FULL_URL: this.SERVER + this.API_VERSION,
 PLAYERS:  this.FULL_URL + '/players',
 TEAMS:    this.FULL_URL + '/teams',
};
```

And on the other side in getGame.js

```
GLOBAL = require('../environement');
function getGame() {
 console.log(GLOBAL.PLAYERS)
}
```

When i run my app i got

```
undefined/players
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this using ES6.

```
const SERVER = 'http://url.com';
const API_VERSION = '/api/v3';

export const FULL_URL = SERVER + API_VERSION;
export const PLAYERS = FULL_URL + '/players';
export const TEAMS = FULL_URL + '/teams';
```

And then

```
import { FULL_URL, PLAYERS, TEAMS } from 'path/to/the/file'
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. Can you edit the server line and delete my URL please? I made a mistake by not changing it.

Comment: @Poptocrack Changed. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to this solution: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config .

Also it will be very helpful when you will be have a few different environments and build agent for app in teamcity for example.